# Inner static generic class <<Cannot be resolved to a type>>

Tags: java, graph

I am trying to make an adjacent list of Graph using **HashMap** and **Generics**.
However, i don`t understand why i get an error "*Edge cannot be resolved to a type*"

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));
        int roads = sc.nextInt(); // How many Edges we have
        int vertices = sc.nextInt(); // How many vertices Graph has
        Graph<String> g = new Graph<String>(vertices); // Every Vertex is a String
        for (int i=0;i<roads;i++) {
            g.add(sc.next(), sc.next());
        }
        //Here i get an error
        Edge<String> e; //Edge cannot be resolved to a type
    }
    static class Graph<E> {
        HashMap<E,Edge<E>> m;

        public Graph(int vertices) {
            m = new HashMap<E,Edge<E>>(vertices);
        }

        public void add(E from,E to) {
            if (m.get(from)==null) m.put(from,new Edge<E>(to,null));
            else m.put(from, new Edge<E>(to,m.get(from)));
        }
        //Storing Graph as an adjacent list of edges
        static class Edge<E> {
            E to;
            Edge<E> prev;
            public Edge(E to, Edge<E> prev) {
                this.to = to;
                this.prev = prev;
            }
        }
        //
    }
}
```

Explain please in detail...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Edge appears to be nested within Graph.

Comment: Edge is inner class of `Graph`. Create it's outside `Graph` as your program does not need as nested.

Comment: I don't see any reason why *any* of these classes should be nested. It's best to avoid nested types unless you need them - life is simpler with just top-level classes.

Comment: You could almost understand `Edge` being nested in `Graph` if `Edge ` were not static.  But in this case, it's just a bit pointless.

Comment: You can make this compile by changing the line to `Graph.Edge<String> e;`, but I agree with the consensus that you don't need nested classes for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try and contain `Edge` in `Graph`. Move it to a parallel class, or an external class. Something like

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));
        int roads = sc.nextInt(); // How many Edges we have
        int vertices = sc.nextInt(); // How many vertices Graph has
        Graph<String> g = new Graph<String>(vertices); // Every Vertex is a
                                                        // String
        for (int i = 0; i < roads; i++) {
            g.add(sc.next(), sc.next());
        }
        // Here i get an error
        Edge<String> e; // Edge cannot be resolved to a type
    }

    static class Graph<E> {
        HashMap<E, Edge<E>> m;

        public Graph(int vertices) {
            m = new HashMap<E, Edge<E>>(vertices);
        }

        public void add(E from, E to) {
            if (m.get(from) == null)
                m.put(from, new Edge<E>(to, null));
            else
                m.put(from, new Edge<E>(to, m.get(from)));
        }
    }

    // Storing Graph as an adjacent list of edges
    static class Edge<E> {
        E to;
        Edge<E> prev;

        public Edge(E to, Edge<E> prev) {
            this.to = to;
            this.prev = prev;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Edge` is an inner class in `Graph`, so inside `Graph` you can just call it `Edge`... but `main` isn't inside `Graph`.

From inside the class `Main` (including the method `main`), you can refer to it as `Graph.Edge` (with a generic argument this would be `Graph.Edge<String>`).

From outside the class `Main`, you can refer to it as `Main.Graph.Edge` (with generics, `Main.Graph.Edge<String>`).